# searching the database objects

Tags: search, database

How can I search SQL server database to find string in any of objects name? I have a problem when testers says this and that is not working and I can not find it by it's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RedGate has a free tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) that will do just that.  It integrates with SQL Server Management Studio and lets you search through all the objects in a database for items containing a specific string and will tell you what it matched and what kind of object it is (table, key, column, etc).

If you want to know more about the specific SQL you can use to do this, you may want to ask at [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: thanx techturtle